# Python: How to join the first and last character of a string in nested list based on a given condition

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list of this form and I want to extract the string R and number at the end. the output can be a nested list or a list in a dictionary.

```
my_list = [['Race 1', 'Race 2', 'Race 3', 'Race 4', 'Race 5', 'Race 6', 'Race 7', 'Race 8', 'Race 9', 'Race 10'], 
['Race 1', 'Race 2', 'Race 3', 'Race 4', 'Race 5', 'Race 6', 'Race 7', 'Race 8', 'Race 9', 'Race 10'], 
['Race 1', 'Race 2', 'Race 3', 'Race 4', 'Race 5', 'Race 6', 'Race 7', 'Race 8', 'Race 9', 'Race 10', 'Race 11', 'Race 12'], 
['Race 1', 'Race 2', 'Race 3', 'Race 4', 'Race 5', 'Race 6', 'Race 7', 'Race 8', 'Race 9', 'Race 10', 'Race 11', 'Race 12'], ['Race 1', 'Race 2', 'Race 3', 'Race 4', 'Race 5', 'Race 6', 'Race 7', 'Race 8', 'Race 9', 'Race 10', 'Race 11', 'Race 12']
]
```

I had to loop through the inner list and extract the alphabet and the numbers at the end. I got the output below. but that is not what I want.

```
race_list = []
for race_number in my_list:
    for i in race_number :
        m = re.split(' |a',i)
        new_str = "".join(m[::len(m)-1]).strip()
        race_list.append(new_str)



  ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11', 'R12', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11', 'R12', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11', 'R12']
```

my output should be of this form

```
[   ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10'], 
   ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10'],
   ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10'],
   ['R11', 'R12', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10'],
   ['R11', 'R12', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4', 'R5', 'R6', 'R7', 'R8', 'R9', 'R10', 'R11', 'R12']
]
```

Comment: If it is as simple as mapping your current nested list to the first character of the string followed by the number after the space, then you could just do `[[item[0] + item.split()[1] for item in nested] for nested in my_list]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to get the first character and the number at the end.

```
race_list = []
for race_number in my_list:
    new_rn = []
    for i in race_number:
        match = re.search(r'^(.).*?(\d+)$', i)
        new_rn.append(match.group(1) + match.group(2))
    race_list.append(new_rn)
```